# Pandas: Drop leading rows with NaN threshold in dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas Dataframe with intermittent NaN values:

```
Index       Col1     Col2      Col3    Col4  Col5  Col6  Col7  Col8 
1991-12-31  100.000  100.000    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN                     
1992-01-31   98.300  101.530    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN                     
1992-02-29   97.602  100.230   98.713   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN                     
1992-03-31   93.473    NaN    102.060   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN                     
1992-04-30   94.529  102.205  107.755   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

I'd like to drop leading rows with 6 NaNs or more. Specifically, in this case, I'd only like to drop row with Indices '1991-12-31' and '1992-01-31'.

Using df.dropna(thresh = 6) doesn't work because it drops row '1992-03-31' as well.

One solution would be to count the NaNs in each row and stop at the first row when the number of NaNs is less than 6.

Any faster/cleaner solution?

EDIT: Edited for clarity and @Alexander's comment

Comment: The '1992-02-29' has 5 NaNs - what's different about it that lets you determine that you don't want to drop it?

Comment: @chrisb, drop *leading* rows.

Comment: All the rows have at least five NaNs. Surely you mean rows with more than 5 NaNs.

Comment: @Alexander thanks for pointing it out. Fixed the question.

Answer (score 3):

You just need `df[(df.irow(0).isnull().sum()>5):]`

When the 1st row has more than 5 `nan`, `df.irow(0).isnull().sum()>5` is `True` and `df[(df.irow(0).isnull().sum()>5):]` is simply `df[1:]`: the 1st row is omitted.

To address @DSM's point, we may consider:

```
df.ix[np.argwhere(df.isnull().sum(1)<=5).ravel()[0]:]
```

Basically this is to slice the DataFrame, from the 1st row (not in the original df, but the 1st row that has less or equal than 5 `nan`) on. This way, if the 1st row has 6, the 2nd row has 7 and the 3rd has 8 `nan`s, the resultant dataframe will start from the 4th row.  If the 1st row has only 1 `nan`, the result will be `df[0:]`, no rows skipped.

Comment: I suspect that if the second row had 8 NaNs, that would also count as a leading row to be dropped.

Comment: Beautiful. This answers the question. I wasn't aware of functionality of ravel and argwhere. Thank you @CTZhu

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the column named `Index` is actually the index, you can count the number of null values in each row and select those that are greater than your threshold.  If any are returned, drop the first one (i.e. the leading row).

```
idx = df[df.isnull().sum(axis=1) <= 5].index
if len(idx) > 0:
    df = df.ix[idx[0]:]

>>> df
              Col1     Col2     Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6  Col7  Col8
Index                                                             
1992-02-29  97.602  100.230   98.713   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1992-03-31  93.473      NaN  102.060   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1992-04-30  94.529  102.205  107.755   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: I need to drop ALL leading rows with > 5 NaNs, not just first one.

Comment: I believe the term 'leading rows' is a bit misleading. Perhaps just 'all rows' with 6 or more NaNs?  If so, the edit above should work where I simply changed idx[0] to idx in the `drop` statement.

Comment: No. I specifically mean 'leading rows'. For 'all rows' I can simply use the df.dropna(thresh = 5). However, this is not the desired output for my question.

Comment: Can you please clarify your definition of 'leading rows'?

Comment: The first 'n' rows which satisfy the condition. If any 1 row doesn't satisfy the condition, then any row after that row also doesn't satisfy the condition.

Comment: What if there was a row on top of the DataFrame (e.g. 1991-09-30) that only had 5 NaNs, i.e. it is a vaild row.  Should it be dropped, or retained?

Comment: Retained. Furthermore, no row should be dropped since leading row doesn't have more than 5 NaNs.